# Как получить текст контрола по хендлу

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

У меня есть хендл контрола, мне нужно получить текст, который он содержит, однако WM_GETTEXT возвращает пустую строку, я предполагаю, что в приложении, с которого я хочу считать данные есть защита, есть какие либо другие способы получения данных, который содержит этот контрол. Может считать из памяти этот объект и найти в нем строку или еще как. Подскажите как это можно реализовать на C# или C++.

P.S. делать скриншот контрола и распознавать на нем текст не выход, необходима быстрая реализация, так чтобы практически в реальном времени можно было считывать из него данные.

код для отправки WM_GETTEXT

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] //
public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wparam,
int lparam);

const int WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
const int WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

public void RegisterControlforMessages()
{
    RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GETTEXT");
}

public string GetControlText(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder();
    Int32 size = SendMessage((int)hWnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0).ToInt32();
    if (size > 0)
    {
        title = new StringBuilder(size + 1);
        SendMessage(hWnd, (int)WM_GETTEXT, title.Capacity, title);
    }
    return title.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Добавьте пример, где возвращается пустая строка.

Comment: У разных контролов текст может и показываться примерно одинаково, но храниться может по разному, и соответственно доступ к нему нужен будет свой. Приведите тип контрола и лучше всего, используя WinSpy++, изображение того что он отдаёт при выборе этого контрола. В нем же мы сможете протестировать отсылку различных сообщений и посмотреть что выходит.

Comment: @alexolut, пример кода добавил.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Добавил скрины

Comment: В поиске большинство результатов ведут на реверсию (http://wasm.in/forum/threads/wm_command-s-neponjatnymi-parametrami.22048/), и Я не уверен что на SO разрешено обсуждать такие темы. К тому же здесь (http://www.progtown.com/topic335306-do-not-work-on-a-text-output.html) говорится что они РИСУЮТ текст, а не добавляют в список как вы думаете.

Comment: Если это кастомный контрол, он вовсе не обязан реагировать на `WM_GETTEXT`.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov хорошо, спасибо